# Error: ')' expected Error: illegal start of expression

Tags: java

```
//8.    
//----------------------------------------------------------------
//-------- Display orignal and encrypted message information
//----------------------------------------------------------------
    private void displayEncryptedMessage(String originalMessage, String encryptedMessage) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Enter Message to be encrypted: ");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("   Plain Text : " + originalMessage);

    }

// 9
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Encrypted it by substituting the character with the corresponding character in the cipher.
// 
//----------------------------------------------------------------
    private void encrypt(String cipher){
      int letterPosition;
      String encryptedMessage = "";
      String originalMessage = Keyboard.readInput();

      displayEncryptedMessage(String originalMessage, String encryptedMessage);

      for (letterPosition=0; letterPosition<originalMessage.length(); letterPosition++){
        char replaceCipherLetter = cipher.charAt(letterPosition);
        encryptedMessage += replaceCipherLetter;}
      System.out.println("   Cipher Text: " + encryptedMessage);
      }
```

Im really new to Java so all your comments will be GREATLY appreciated... SInce method 8. is void, it doesnt return any values right? If I wanted to put 8 into 9,   `displayEncryptedMessage(String originalMessage, String encryptedMessage);` , is that what Id put as the parameters ? and why do I get these errors?

```
  Error: ')' expected 
  Error: illegal start of expression
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is wrapped up in a class of some sort?

Answer (score 11):

When you are calling the method , you have to only pass the values , type declaration is not allowed while method calling.

```
displayEncryptedMessage(String originalMessage, String encryptedMessage);
```

should be

```
 displayEncryptedMessage(originalMessage, encryptedMessage);
```

Comment: oh, I see, what do you mean by pass values and method calling though? Thanks

Comment: When you declare a method , you need to specify the type of arguments that your method can take , that you had already did at #8. Now when you want to invoke the method as you are doing inside #9 you have to pass the values that you declared as in #8. Hope it answers your question. You can refer this tutorial for more - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm

Comment: @RafNimitoAel Your latter question can't be serious, can it? Why do you write methods then?

Comment: Ah, I see... Oh we didnt really get taught 'exactly' what those terms meant

Comment: No worries mate, just a suggestion refer some good book and try to understand in  more depth. - thanks

Answer (score 0):

While calling the method, you need to pass the values like:

```
displayEncryptedMessage(originalMessage, encryptedMessage);
```

Declaring the type of parameter that method will accept, is part of method definition.

```
Note: Method can also accept the Type or Subtype of the type.
```